# Django - filter drop down choices based on user group

Tags: python, django, django-forms

i am trying to filter a forms drop down list based on a users group

To find the user group i am using a custom templatetag

**template tag**

```
from django import template 

register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name='in_group')
def in_group(user,group_name):
    try:
        group=Group.objects.get(name=group_name)
    except Group.DoesNotExist:
        return False
    return group in user.groups.all()
```

**task.html**

```
  {% load group_check %}

<form method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {% if user.is authenticated %}
  {% if requset.user|in_group:'DEVELOPER' %}
    #...DO SOMETHING

  {{ form.as_p }}



  <button type="submit">add task</button>
</form>
```

**models**

```
GOALS_TYPE= (('DT','Daily Task'),
        ('WT','Weekly Task'),
        ('V','Verified'),
        ('D','Done'),
)

class GoalStatus(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=254, null=True) 
    task_id=models.IntegerField(default=1,null=False)
    description =models.CharField(max_length=254)
    verified_by=models.ForeignKey('ScrumyUser', on_delete= models.CASCADE, null=True)
    status=models.CharField(choices=GOALS_TYPE, max_length=2, default='DT')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

the template for the form is based on the forms.py

**forms.py**

```
class ChangeTaskForm(forms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = GoalStatus
    fields = ('title', 'task_id','description','status', 'verified_by')
```

**views.py**

```
def move_goals(request,pk):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    form = ChangeTaskForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/index/')
  else:
    form = ChangeTaskForm()
  return render(request, 'oderascrumy/task.html', {'form': form})
```

**urls.py**

```
 path('task/<pk>/', views.move_goals, name='move_goals')
```

so for example if the user is in group "developer", the drop down choices for status will be only verified and done

Comment: so what's the question?

Comment: if the user for example is in group DEVELOPER, the drop down choices available in the form will be only verified and done,

Comment: It doesn't work, are you trying to achieve something, where's the whole html code

Comment: it works i should add the views and urls perhaps,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like below

> views.py

```
def move_goals(request,pk):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    form = ChangeTaskForm(request.POST, user=request.user)
    if form.is_valid():
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/index/')
  else:
    form = ChangeTaskForm(user=request.user)
  return render(request, 'oderascrumy/task.html', {'form': form})
```

> forms.py

```
class ChangeTaskForm(forms.ModelForm):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
     user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
     super(ChangeTaskForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
     if user.groups.filter(name='DEVELOPER').exists():
        self.fields['status'].choices = (('V','Verified'), ('D','Done'),)
  class Meta:
    model = GoalStatus
    fields = ('title', 'task_id','description','status', 'verified_by')
```

> template.html

```
<form method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.as_p }}
  <button type="submit">add task</button>
</form>
```

I think no need of template tag for this.

Comment: if user.groups.filter(name='DEVELOPER').exists():, this line throws an error **'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'**, so can group be an object of user, or is there a better way to filter?

Comment: @OderaOkonkwo are you sending user to form in views.py `form = ChangeTaskForm(user=request.user)` ?

Comment: yes i did that in my views, but it still throws up the error

Comment: @OderaOkonkwo copy paste the above code. It should work.

Comment: it works fine now, i must have typed something different, i just copied and pasted and it worked, thank you!

Comment: can you point me to documentation, on this so that i understand it better, for the forms.py method you used